# What is a dual field?

Tags: gauge-theory, duality, strong-force, cp-violation, gluons

Can you give me an intuitive, physical understanding of a "dual field"? For example, the [Hodge dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual) of the gluon field strength matrix $F$ is $\tilde{F}_{\mu \nu}=\epsilon_{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} F^{\alpha \beta}$. What is its physical significance? Why for example does it appear in the strong CP problem where we have the $\theta$-parameter in the Lagrangian $L_\theta = \theta F \tilde{F}$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "intuitive, physical understanding". What, for example, is your "intuitive, physical understanding" of $F$ itself? Also, whether the dual "appears" in something or not is a matter of how you write it. The usual kinetic term for a gauge field, $F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$ is from some viewpoint more naturally written as $F\wedge\star F$, so the Hodge dual also appears in the kinetic term, while the CP violating term is more naturally written $\theta(F\wedge F)$ without a dual. So the question "why does it appear" is not well-defined.

Comment: If you want a more intuitive understanding of form fields themselves (and Hodge duals), the standard "picture" is presented in Misner, Thorne and Wheeler's Gravitation.

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/744511/226902 and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/647435/226902

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to talk about the Hodge dual in electromagnetism to give you a physical intuition.

In electromagnetism the appearance of the Hodge dual field is a mathematical manifestation of [electromagnetic duality](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~jmf/Teaching/Lectures/EDC.pdf). Roughly speaking, if some divine being swapped the electric and magnetic fields, fundamental physics wouldn't change. Of course, this statement is only correct if you believe in [magnetic sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) which have been hypothesised but never observed.

You can get more of an intuition for the action of the Hodge dual by rewriting the field strength $F$ in terms of more familiar $\mathbf{E}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ fields. Explicitly the definition is

$$F^{0i}=-E^i \quad F^{ij}=\epsilon^{ijk}B_k$$

It is then an easy exercise to check that applying the Hodge star is equivalent to the map

$$(\mathbf{E},\mathbf{B})\to (\mathbf{B},-\mathbf{E})$$

Clearly electromagnetic duality is a symmetry of the QED Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L}\sim F \tilde F \sim F \wedge \star F$$

Indeed applying the Hodge dual twice gets you back to (minus) the identity, hence the map $F \to \star F$ leaves $\mathcal{L}$ invariant (up to sign).

I'll leave it to you to check that the duality holds at the level of Maxwell's equations (with sources). If you're stuck, take a look at the notes I linked above.

Finally note that the Hodge dual has (in principle) nothing to do with the $\theta$ parameter! You can write down Yang-Mills theory without considering $\theta$ and you'd still get a $\tilde F$ in the Lagrangian. The $\theta$ is in fact a manifestation of the topological structure of solutions to the Yang-Mills equations - a so-called instanton effect. This is an advanced topic, which deserves it's own question!

Note: you can get analogues of electromagnetic duality in Yang-Mills theories, but typically you require supersymmetry for this. In that case, the duality is referred to as S-duality, and does involve changing the $\theta$ parameter in general. If you're feeling brave, head over to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiberg_duality) and follow some references.